# Rails admin act as taggable not showing tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have an issue with Rails admin gem and act as taggable gem.
I am using heroku. It is just not showing tags, but when i delete tags data and will add new it will show new tags.
On localhost it is working too when I delete data from database. It is just blank

[image]

```
field :terrains
field :themes
field :activities
field :title do
  label "Tagline"
end    
field :intro do
  label "Overview"
end
field :highlights do
  label "What we love"
end
```